# Merge rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query to know how many users have  6 or more activities per month but I only have the relation not the count per month

this is my query

```
SELECT 
MONTH(12_main.timestamp)  AS 'MONTH' ,

  (SELECT 12_main.user )AS 'USER'

 FROM 12_main
 
 INNER JOIN 12_pack on 12_main.pack =12_pack.pack_id 
 INNER JOIN 12_ubication_pack on 12_pack.pack_id= 12_ubication_pack.pack 
 INNER JOIN 10_working_ubication on 12_ubication_pack.ubication =10_working_ubication.id 
 INNER JOIN 12_productive_areas on 10_working_ubication.working_line=12_productive_areas.working_line 

 WHERE 12_main.status_cert ='4' 
 AND YEAR(12_main.timestamp)='2023' 

GROUP BY 12_main.user
HAVING count( * )>=6
;
```

that give me this

| MONTH | USER |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | JUAN12 |
| 1 | MARY23 |
| 2 | JOS123 |
| 2 | DAN454 |
| 3 | ROB345 |

AND I WANT
the months and the quantity of users

| MONTH | USER |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying using group by with the month so the the code looking as following which will solve the issue

```
SELECT 
MONTH(12_main.timestamp) AS 'MONTH' , 
COUNT(DISTINCT 12_main.user) AS 'USER_COUNT' 
FROM 12_main 

INNER JOIN 12_pack ON 12_main.pack = 12_pack.pack_id 
INNER JOIN 12_ubication_pack ON 12_pack.pack_id = 12_ubication_pack.pack 
INNER JOIN 10_working_ubication ON 12_ubication_pack.ubication = 
10_working_ubication.id 
INNER JOIN 12_productive_areas ON 10_working_ubication.working_line = 
12_productive_areas.working_line 

WHERE 12_main.status_cert = '4' 
AND YEAR(12_main.timestamp) = '2023' 

GROUP BY MONTH(12_main.timestamp) HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT 12_main.user) >= 6;
```